# How to efficiently aggregate across multiple models in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have a somewhat complicated situation so bear with me. I have 4 models:

1. MainCategory
2. Category (foreign key to Main)
3. Cat (m2m with Category)
4. Dog (m2m with Category)

My general JSON output would be something like this:

```
[ {name: 'coat_type',
   cat_count: 3,
   dog_count: 5,
   total_count: 8, 
   sub_cats: [ {name: 'furry', cat_count: 1, dog_count: 3, total_count: 4}, 
               {name: 'shaggy', cat_count: 2, dog_count: 2, total_count: 4} ],

  {name: 'facial_features', ... } ]
```

So here is my set of queries, which I don't think is too efficient:

```
output = []

for main_cat in MainCategory.objects.all():
    ...
    sub_cats = Category.objects.filter(main_category=main_cat)
    counts = sub_cats.annotate(
        cat_count = Count('cat', distinct=True),
        dog_count = Count('dog', distinct=True),
        #how do i aggregate total count here?
        #total_count = cat_count + dog_count 
    ).values('name', 'ip_count', 'doc_count', 'total_count')

    main_cat_dict = {
        'name': main_cat.name,
        'sub_cats': counts,
        ...
    }
    output.append(main_cat_dict)
```

I think the sub-category aggregation is okay, but the problem is I still have to loop through each MainCategory. Also I'm not sure how to count total inside each sub-category.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of `Category.objects.filter(main_category=main_cat)` you can use: `main_cat.category_set.all()`, details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
sub_cats = Category.objects.filter(main_category__in=MainCategory.objects.all())
```

And then do the annotations and `values` call as you did before. Of course you can first filter on the `MainCategory` model to exclude some main categories.

It is not possible (at least not with the standard Django ORM) to annotate based on other annotations. It is easier to do some post-processing in Python to get the total count for each entry:

```
for d in sub_cats:
    d['total_count'] = d['cat_count'] + d['dog_count']
```

Comment: Sorry I think I'm misunderstanding something, doesn't your query just get all the Categories? I don't follow how that can output the two-level JSON that I want. The inner-level aggregates cat/dog counts on single sub-category, the outer-level aggregates on the main category, which is just the sum of the sub-categories